# How to plot z(y) if I know z(x) and y(x)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How to plot z(y) if I know z(x) and y(x)?

```
m = 1
```

y(x) is

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] + 0.3 x^-3)], 
   y[1] == 1}, {y}, {x, 0.4, 1.6}]
```

and z(x) is

```
z[x] = 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3
```

(I am sorry I forgot to give m before)

Comment: You say `and z(x) is z[y] = 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3` should this not be `and z(x) is z[x] = 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3` ?

Comment: yes.It should be z[x] = 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3

Answer (score 4):

> How to plot z(y) if I know z(x) and y(x)?

After you find $y(x)$, find the inverse function $g(y)=inv(y(x))$ then plot $z(y)=z(g(y))$

Flow diagram

[image]

```
ClearAll[x,y,z];
m=1;
sol=y/.First@NDSolve[{y'[x]==m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7+0.05 Log[1/x]+
       0.3 x^-3)],y[1]==1},{y},{x,0.4,1.6}];
z[x_]:=0.7+0.05 Log[1/x]-0.05/3;
```

Now

```
 Plot[Evaluate[sol[x]],{x,0.4,1.6},PlotLabel->"y[x]"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[z[x],{x,0.4,1.6},PlotLabel->"z[x]"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then to plot $z(y)$

```
zy[y_] := z[InverseFunction[sol][y]]
Plot[zy[y],{y,.9,1.2},AxesLabel->{"y","z(y)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot). Here are your equations (I set `m=1`):

```
m = 1;
yy = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] + 0.3 x^-3)], y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0.4, 1.6}];

z[x_] := 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3
```

Then, [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot) gives:

```
ParametricPlot[{yy[x], z[x]}, {x, 0.4, 1.6}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

iIf you're interesting in obtaining an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) approximation to `z[y]`, here's one way to do it. First, let's define:

```
eqn = z[y] == ζ[x[y]];
```

where:

```
ζ[x_] := 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3
```

Differentiate:

```
D[eqn, y] //TeXForm
```

> $z'(y)=-\frac{0.05` x'(y)}{x(y)}$

Next, you're ODE is:

```
y'[x] == f[x];
```

where:

```
f[x_] := m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] + 0.3 x^-3)]
```

We can invert this to have:

```
x'[y] == 1/f[x[y]] //TeXForm
```

> $x'(y)=\frac{4.47213595499958` x(y)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{0.3`}{x(y)^3}+0.05` \log \left(\frac{1}{x(y)}\right)+0.7`}}}$

This gives us a system of 2 ODEs. The initial conditions are:

```
x[1] == 1
z[1] == ζ[x[1]]
```

> x[1] == 1
>
> z[1] == 0.683333 + 0.05 Log[1/x[1]]

Putting these together we have:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {D[eqn, y], x'[y] == 1/f[x[y]], x[1] == 1, z[1] == ζ[1]},
    z,
    {y, 0.5,2}
];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At y == 0.785205689705119`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Plotting yields the same output:

```
Plot[sol[y], {y, 0.86, 1.1}]
```

[image]

To answer @Nasser's comment:

```
sol[.9]
```

> 0.709708

Comment: I am not able to understand your solution to check it with what I have. For example, what would your solution give for z(y), when y=.9? my solution gives `zy[0.9] = 0.709`.

Comment: @Nasser  when x=0.6 ，he got `yy[0.6]=0.903` and `z[0.6]=0.709` ,
then put point(0.903,0.709) on the y-z coordinate axis.

Comment: The problem statement is literally begging for `ParametricPlot[]` to be used. :)

Comment: @Nasser See update.

Answer (score 1):

You have z[x] and with DSolve you get y[x], so to get z[y], you need z[x[y]]

```
m=1:

ysol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 
m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] + 0.3 x^-3)], y[1] == 1};

xx = InverseFunction[y /. ysol][y]

z[x_] := .7 + .05 Log[1/x] - .05/3

Plot[z[xx], {y, .9, 1.2}]
```

[image]

Comment: may be I am missing something, but how is this different from what I have above?

Answer (score 0):

May use the command [Composition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

```
m = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 
    m/x Sqrt[0.05/(0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] + 0.3 x^-3)], 
   y[1] == 1}, {y}, {x, 0.4, 1.6}]
ysol = y /. sol[[1]]
z[x_] = 0.7 + 0.05 Log[1/x] - 0.05/3;

f[x_] = z@*ysol@x
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.4, 1.6}]
```

Comment: I don't think that's right,
If `f[x_] = z@*ysol@x`, the variable is x, and I want to plot z (y).